# Flutter How I could setState when variable change?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

How I could `setState` when variable change?

I can't find a way to do this, and I'm a beginner in Flutter.

My code:

```
// i need to setState when width change
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,

  child: Text(content,
  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
    maxLines: 50,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need do anything, flutter will automatically rebuild the widget when `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/height` changes.

Comment: I am using listVeiw.sperated and dont work but without it it works